# "Cannot find this file" error when deploying from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, site, site-definition

I'm getting an error in Visual Studio 2010 after pressing F5 to Debug:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Add
>   Solution': Error: Cannot find this
>   file specified in the manifest file:
>   G2_SiteDefinition_List_Instances_Feature\ListInstance1\Elements.xml

But elements.xml file is there with the ListIntance1 folder. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you verify that the file is actually in the wsp? If you rename from .wsp to .cab, you should be able to open it to view what files are in there.

Comment: @Laurie: You are correct. ListIntances1 folder with it's contents did not make to wsp? Why is that? the folder is not excluded from the solution (or project).

Answer (score 4):

Open the feature that includes the project item and expand the files node on the project item to verify the files that are included with the item. I suspect that your elements file will not be displayed. You need open the properties for the elements file (open the file and click F4), and make sure that the type on the file is set to "ElementManifest".

Comment: The problem is fixed but Now i have a this issue when I debug. Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id 'f4578011-7474-45cd-ad91-d16ad4decaf4' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope. This is the feature ID for the list instance feature.

Answer (score 1):

Please, check, if the ListInstance1 item is added into your feature (in feature designer)

Also, I can recommend you to check out this awesome Visual Studio Plugin, made by Microsoft MVP Waldek Mastykarz:

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/easier-working-sharepoint-project-items-mavention-spi-references/

This could help you to work with project items in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Omlin: I edited the list feature to give it a new GUID.

Comment: @Omlin: I discarded my changes and VS put the old guid back. and I made sure webtemplate now has this GUID. But now I get another error when I do F5. Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id 'f4578011-7474-45cd-ad91-d16ad4decaf4' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope. This is the feature ID for the list instance feature.

Comment: Did you also modify the feature scope?

Comment: I think you can simply change feature guid, you can generate a new one with Tools => Create GUID

Comment: @Omlin: Okay I changed the GUID again. But apparently I have a something (like workflow or something) in visual studio project (a project that was based on WSP I downloaded from production server) that depends on a list that does not exist in the farm. How do I find out the object that depending on certain guid (in visual studio project)

Comment: You can try to find this GUID in your solution (Ctrl+Shift+F). Also you can use add-in, which I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Omlin: Yes sir, i did that search too and it keeps on brining List_Instances_Feature.feature but when go into edit mode of that page i dont see the GUID being there.

Comment: :) That is most likely hiding under the Designer tab, `[+] Feature activation dependencies`.

Comment: Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id 'f4578011-7474-45cd-ad91-d16ad4decaf4' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope. I cannot debug. Any help....

Comment: hmm, so it is the same feature, looks like nothing changed.

Comment: @omlin: first i was having trouble because wsp (after package) did not include 2 of the list instances. so, now that fixed. but i am unable to deploy. see error posted before. I am about to pull my hair. I thought SP 2010 has gotten better but seems like I am back to SP 2007 development.

Comment: Scope
Lists feature Web
Modules feature Web
Web Template Site
Web Events Web
PropertyBag feature Web

Comment: @Roxanne, so you have just changed the feature ID, but error message still points to the old one. How could that happen? :) Try reopen Visual Studio please, something impossible is starting to happen.

Comment: I know that this thread is quite old but I found by using google with same problem of nof founding file. Your answers with "change .wsp to .cab and look inside" was very helpful, it gave me the hint that > I had to change inside file Feature1.Template.xml the line `<ElementManifest Location="Elements.xml>` to `<ElementsManifest Location=MyNameOfEmptyElement\Elements.xml>`. After that I ran also into the problem with > Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id '449f93da-7b7a-4fd7-86d7-afc017680a1c' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope Bec

Answer (score 1):

Better create a new List Definition and see the columns that you specify in Elements.xml appear in the Custom Columns through Site Settings and update

Answer (score 0):

In the solution ,**solutionname.feature > manifest tab** .
You can find "**Items in the solution**" and "**Items in the feature**". 
My list definition files in "**Items in solution**". So I moved these files to "**items in the feature**". That solved my problem

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98269/error-occured-in-the-deployment-step-add-solution-error-cannot-find-this-file/187291#187291). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!