# Error Occured in the deployment step 'Add Solution': error cannot find this file specified in the manifest file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I created one more SharePoint Project in my solution which has a module with pages. But this solution keeps on deploying the solution in a folder at ..../14/TEMPLATE/FEATURES/**ProjectName_FeatureName**, I want it to be just /**ProjectName** so I updated the package file accordingly.

Now I am getting this error saying it is not getting feature manifest file but I see Feature.xml file the packaged wsp file.

What am I missing here, please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try these steps:

- Create new sharepoint project, select "Empty" template, give name for
  your project
- Now right click on your project, select 'Add'>New Item and select
  "Module" from sharepoint template, give name   (keep in mind this is
  your feature name...)
- It automatically creates Module.xml (you can called as element.xml)
  and sample.txt
- Add custom pages or do any think what you want
- Simply press F5, then automatically create solution, copy assemply to
  GAC, also create new feature folder in 12 hive, and deploy in your
  sharepoint site...
  [Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0aa9ba9f-c6ec-49dc-b258-098ba38ad9de/error-cannot-find-this-file-specified-in-the-manifest-file)

http://planetjai.blogspot.com/2010/09/cannot-find-this-file-specified-in.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still my problem is when I add the module the package manifest has this for Feature Manifest Location                                      <FeatureManifests>
    <FeatureManifest Location="ProjectName_Feature1\FeatureName.xml" />
  </FeatureManifests>   and when I remove that feature name, it is not finding the feature manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Package > Manifest Tab > FeatureManifest Location

using Edit Options, you can overwrite the xml.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution ,**solutionname.feature > manifest tab** .
You can find "**Items in the solution**" and "**Items in the feature**". 
My list definition files in "**Items in solution**". So I moved these files to "**items in the feature**". That solved my problem